# Issue in the jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I've following jQuery code:

```
$('.btnAdd').click(function () {
  $('#blacklistgrid > tbody:last').append('<tr id="Row2">
                          <td><input type="text" name="pack[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                          <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                          <td><input type="text" name="volume[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                          <td>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <select name="units[]" class="form-control">
                                <option value="" {if $all_volume_units.id==''} selected='selected'{/if}>Select Unit</option>
                                {foreach from=$all_volume_units item=units key=key} 
                                <option value="{$units.id}" {if $units.id == $all_volume_units.id} selected="selected"{/if}>{$units.unit}</option>
                                {/foreach}
                              </select>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input type="text" name="amount[]" value="" class="form-control" size="9"/>
                          </td>
                        </tr>');
  });
});
```

I'm getting the following syntax error in firebug console:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
[Break On This Error]   

$('#blacklistgrid > tbody:last').append('<tr id="Row2">
```

I'm not getting why this error is coming. Note that each and every bit I used in append() is essential though you can correct the quotes if I've made any mistake in manipulating them.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have multi-line strings like you're using.  You can put a \ at the end of each line in the string as a continuation character to the next line.  Or, you can make each line a separate stand-alone string and use `+` between them to join them all.

Comment: @jfriend00:Can you please post acompletely corrected version mof my code as an answer, please?

Comment: Another thing is `'`. Whenever You use `'` you should use `\` before, otherwise You will get more than one string. Eg. `$all_volume_units.id==''` should be `$all_volume_units.id==\'\'`. Cheers.

Comment: I don't intend to write your code for you.  The problem has been explained to you.  If you don't understand some part of the explanation, you can ask further questions.  It sounds like you should also do some reading about how javascript literal strings are defined, including how you use quotes inside a string.

Comment: @PHPLover Or, are you trying to do this ? .append('<tr id="Row2" />')

Comment: Can this question be closed as "simple typographical error"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the string in each line or use `\` to join *multi-line string*. Also make sure that you have wring combination of single and double quotes, anything like this is wrong `'"'"`

```
$('.btnAdd').click(function () {
    $('#blacklistgrid > tbody:last').append('<tr id="Row2"> \
                          <td><input type="text" name="pack[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td> \
                          <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td> \
                          <td><input type="text" name="volume[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td> \
                          <td> \
                            <div class="btn-group"> \
                              <select name="units[]" class="form-control"> \
                                <option value="" {if $all_volume_units.id==""} selected="selected {/if}>Select Unit</option> \
                                {foreach from=$all_volume_units item=units key=key}  \
                                <option value="{$units.id}" {if $units.id ==  $all_volume_units.id} selected="selected"{/if}>{$units.unit}</option>\
                                {/foreach} \
                              </select>\
                            </div>\
                          </td>\
                          <td>\
                            <input type="text" name="amount[]" value="" class="form-control" size="9"/>\
                          </td>\
                        </tr>');
});
```

**OR**, use string concatenation

```
$('#blacklistgrid > tbody:last').append('<tr id="Row2">'+
     '<td><input type="text" name="pack[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>'
```

Comment: Can you please post a complete corrected version of my code?

Comment: @PHPLover, you just need to follow the answer, put a \ after every line of your string literals

Answer (score 2):

there is some syntax error, correct multiline error and escape single quote in string

```
$('.btnAdd').click(function () {
 $('#blacklistgrid > tbody:last').append('<tr id="Row2">' +
                      '<td><input type="text" name="pack[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>' +
                      '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>' +
                      '<td><input type="text" name="volume[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>' +
                      '<td>' +
                        '<div class="btn-group">' +
                          '<select name="units[]" class="form-control">' +
                            '<option value="" {if $all_volume_units.id==\'\'} selected=\'selected\'{/if}>Select Unit</option>' +
                            '{foreach from=$all_volume_units item=units key=key} ' +
'<option value="{$units.id}" {if $units.id == $all_volume_units.id} selected="selected" {/if}>{$units.unit}</option>' +
'{/foreach}' +
'</select>' +
'</div>' +
'</td>' +
'<td>' +
'<input type="text" name="amount[]" value="" class="form-control" size="9"/>' +
'</td>' +
'</tr>');
});
```